# Google finance quotes search box

Tags: python, google-finance-api

Trying to implement a web service which should have exactly the same function as http://www.google.com/finance  the search quotes box

when user type the stock name or company name, the right stock name is suggested while typing.
my service will using historical information from google finance, so get proper quote name from google is a must!

anyone knows where i could find this quote list through google finance api?   better with python.

or anyone can suggest some ideas please?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Google Finance API is documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/).

To access it from Python, use the [gdata python client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/).